# Finding specific heat

Tags: thermodynamics, phase-transition

How would you find the specific heat of an ice/water mixture as it melts? My problem with this is that during this time the change in temperature would be zero. Wouldn't this make the specific heat undefined?

Comment: Why would you want to know the SHC of the mixtures? Is this a practical issue about *measuring* specific heat, or a semantic (philosophical) issue about the *meaning* or *definition* of SHC for such a mixture?

Comment: Does it say "specific heat capacity"?  It might be looking for the "specific" heat of fusion.

Comment: The heat capacity during a first-order phase transition is infinite, as you have determined.

Answer (score 1):

Ice and water have different specific heat capacities (SHC). You could define the SHC of the mixture as a weighted average of the SHCs for ice and water. If the mixture has reached equilibrium, and heat is not entering or leaving it, then the ratio of ice to water is constant, so the weighted average SHC is also constant. However, such a definition is not useful, because a measurement of the SHC requires heat to enter or leave the mixture.

You are correct in saying that the average temperature of the mixture is constant while the ice melts. Whether you put thermal energy into the ice-water mixture or remove it, the temperature does not change until it is all the same phase (all ice or all water). So practically the SHC is infinite (or undefined as you say, because of division by zero).

Comment: If one plots the average energy versus temperature, starting well below the transition temperature and going well above, then one should observe a discontinuity of this average energy at the transition temperature corresponding to the latent heat. Therefore, defining the specific heat as the derivative of the average energy with respect to temperature, there should be a  Dirac peak at the transition temperature. I would be tempted to conclude that the specific heat is infinite! A small change of energy leads to no temperature change. Anyone could confirm?

Comment: @Christophe I do not see how this is a comment on my answer. Comments are not for discussion, so asking others for confirmation is not appropriate. You ought to post your comment as your own answer. Then other users can vote and comment on it.

Comment: @Christophe Yes, sorry, my mistake. Zero change in temperature implies infinite heat capacity. I will correct my answer.

Comment: I think it's worth noting that this question says "specific heat" not "specific heat capacity".  I'm pretty sure I've heard latent heat of fusion referred to as "specific heat of fusion" before.  It seems possible that the question could be based on that, and there is some disconnect between what OP was asked, and what is in the question here.

Comment: @JMac True the question could be clearer on this point. However, I don't think that interpretation works in the context of the question. Also, many websites do use *specific heat* when they mean *specific heat capacity* - eg [HyperPhysics](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/thermo/spht.html), [Indiana Uni Chemistry Notes](http://www.iun.edu/~cpanhd/C101webnotes/matter-and-energy/specificheat.html), [Wolfram World of Physics](http://scienceworld.wolfram.com/physics/SpecificHeat.html),
 [SoftSchools](http://www.softschools.com/formulas/physics/specific_heat_formula/61/) etc

Comment: @sammygerbil It doesn't work in the context of OP's question; but I'm thinking more about the question that is motivating OP's question.  Clearly "How would you find the specific heat of an ice/water mixture as it melts?" comes from somewhere.  Maybe it was just a thought experiment; but based on OP's concern with the premise of his own question, I doubt it was self-driven.  This is why I'm thinking there is a disconnect between what OP is asking us, and the motivation for the question.  I agree that using "specific heat" is going to be interpreted as "specific heat capacity" in general.